# Forcing IE9 to render as IE8, but still using CSS3 properties

Tags: html, css

I'm using `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">` to make IE9 render as IE8. This has fixed a lot of my issues, however because IE8 doesn't have support for `box-shadow` I was forced to use `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#333333', Direction=145, Strength=5);` to get a similar effect to my shadow. Now, IE9 does have support for `box-shadow` however i can't get IE9 to use `box-shadow` instead of the `filter`.

Does anyone know how to get IE9 to render the shadow?

Comment: It is obvious that `box-shadow` no longer works because you forced IE9 to render the website as IE8. Remove the `X-UA-Compatible` header and `box-shadow` will work.

Comment: The `Shadow` filter looks *very* bad.

Comment: So, why are you making IE9 render as IE8 anyway? Surely your time would be better spent fixing the issues that prevent IE9 rendering correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make IE9 use its native `box-shadow` if it's in IE8 mode.

You can:

- Just use IE9 mode and fix your page to work in it - this is what I'd do.
- Use [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/) - it can simulate `box-shadow` in IE6-8.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you forcing it to render as IE8 then expecting it to render as IE9? :) IE8 didn't have box-shadow support, so IE9 dutifully disables it when it's rendering as IE8.

If you want IE9 to render the box-shadow you'll have to set it back to rendering as IE9 or EDGE. If you are forced to maintain the x-ua-compatible as it is, then you'll have to use filters.

Note there's different syntax for IE8...

```
/* For IE 8 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000')";
/* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000');
```

(example grabbed from http://robertnyman.com/2010/03/16/drop-shadow-with-css-for-all-web-browsers/)

Because these are pretty nasty ideally I'd suggest you isolate them in an IE-only stylesheet delivered with conditional comments.